# R: Group adjacent object in vector

Tags: r, vector

I've a big vector of 200,000 objects. The vector contains integers values. And the vector is sorted. How can I split the vector in chunk of adjacent points.

Example :

```
x <- c(1,4,5,6,8,9,20,21,30)
```

Will give me (here a R list as a result) :

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 4 5 6

[[3]]
[1] 8 9

[[4]]
[1] 20 21

[[5]]
[1] 30
```

The basic way would be to loop across the values but it's not very efficient. Any ideas ?

Comment: How do you decide which are the adjacent points?

Comment: All values in the vector are integers. To be adjacent values have to be at a distance of 1 frome each other. Example : 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `diff` with `cumsum` to create a grouping variable and `split` the `vector`

```
unname(split(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x)!=1))))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 4 5 6

#[[3]]
#[1] 8 9

#[[4]]
#[1] 20 21

#[[5]]
#[1] 30
```